# tikz spacing between circles

Tags: spacing, circles

How to reduce distance between circles ? and how to colorize each circle ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=30cm,paperwidth=35cm,margin=1in,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8] % 
% center
\path  (0,0) coordinate(A);
% circles
\foreach \rr in {2,...,10}{
  \draw  (A) circle (\rr);
}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: You need to tell us more... Do you want a different colour for each circle? In that case, which colours would you like to use? Is the number of circles likely to change?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using a range in `\foreach`, I'm presuming that the number of circles is flexible; therefore, the number of colours involved should also be flexible.

Here is how I would do it.

- Make the loop variable (called `\n`, below) vary over a range of integers (from 1 to the total number of circles to be drawn).
- Use the `\foreach`'s `evaluate` key to generate the value of each radius (called `\rr` below) on the basis of that loop variable.
- Use `\foreach`'s `evaluate` key to generate a value between 0 and 100 (called `\sat` below) and use that value to change the circles' colour linearly between two colours (red and blue, for instance).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=30cm,paperwidth=35cm,margin=1in,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8] % 
% center
\path  (0,0) coordinate(A);
% circles
\def\Rfactor{0.5}                   % multiplying factor
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\nbcircles{9}  % number of circles to draw
\foreach[
  var=\n,
  evaluate=\n as \rr using \Rfactor*(\n+1),
  evaluate=\n as \sat using 100/(\nbcircles-1)*(\n-1),
] \rr in {1,...,\nbcircles}
{
  \draw[blue!\sat!red]  (A) circle (\rr);
}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```