# How to use \x from \foreach loop in the parameters of \draw in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

In order to make it simple, I want to draw concentric circles fading out with something like

```
\foreach \x in {1,1.5,...,4}
\draw[color=black!{100-10*\x}!white] (0,0) circle (\x);
```

The problem is I don't know if there is a way to make some maths in the parameters of the \draw function. Is there a way ?

(I could solve the problem by doing something like

```
\foreach \x in {10,15,...,40}
\draw[color=white!\x!black] (5,0) circle ({0.1*\x});
```

But I really want to know if its possible to do it the other way)

Also, why something like

```
\foreach \x in {10,15,...,40}
\draw[color=white!\x!black] (5,0) circle ({0.1*\x} cm); %note the cm
```

does not work?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174902/tikz-spacing-between-circles

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do some thing like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \foreach \x in {1,1.5,...,4}
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmp}{100-\x*20}
       \draw[color=blue!\tmp!green] (0,0) circle (\x);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Calculate the value outside, store it in a macro (possibly truncate if you want as I did) and then use the macro.

Applying the same strategy to your last query:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \foreach \x in {10,15,...,40}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{0.1*\x}
        \draw[color=white!\x!black] (5,0) circle (\tmp cm);       
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option as suggested by **Torbjørn T.** is to use `evaluate`:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \foreach [evaluate=\x as \y using 100-20*\x] \x in {1,1.5,...,4} 
      \draw[color=blue!\y!green] (0,0) circle (\x);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In your last example every second circle is the same size as the previous because you've used `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`, use `\pgfmathsetmacro` instead. You could also add a solution with `evaluate`, i.e. `\foreach [evaluate=\x as \y using 100-10*\x] \x in {1,1.5,...,8}
\draw[color=black!\y!white,very thick] (0,0) circle (\x);`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. My bad. I didn't notice it. Now corrected. I have added `evaluate` option too. Many thanks for both suggestions :-)

Answer (score 2):

With `\multido` you can define more than one variable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,multido}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \multido{\r=1+0.5,\i=80+-5}{8}{%
       \draw[color=blue!\i!green] (0,0) circle (\r);}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```