# Why am I unable to apply a gradient color to this figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm not very good at latex and looking here on how to apply a gradient to an image I found a post that is basically what I want.

[The post I used](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195244/how-to-use-x-from-foreach-loop-in-the-parameters-of-draw-in-tikz)

With the post code, I get the following image

[image: Expected]

However, when using the same logic

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmax=120,ymax=5, samples=50]
        \foreach \b in {1,1.2,...,4}{
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmp}{100-\x*20}
            \addplot [blue!\tmp!green,thick,domain=0:360,smooth] plot ({(2^2-\b^2)/(2*\b)*(\b*cos(\x))^3},
             {(2^2-\b^2)/(2*\b)*(-2*(sin(\x))^3)});
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get the following result:

[image: Result]

With an error

Does anyone know what's going on? Or the right way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not understand how you got your output, I got errors, and the plotted function does not really give ellipses. The main issue, though, is that

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmp}{100-\x*20}
```

should really be

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmp}{100-\b*20}
```

i.e. a `\b` instead of the `\x`. And then there is a an issue with the expansion of the `\addplot` commands.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmax=120,ymax=5, samples=50]
        \foreach \b in {1,1.2,...,4}{
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmp}{100-\b*20}
            \edef\temp{
            \noexpand\addplot [blue!\tmp!green,thick,domain=0:360,smooth] 
            plot ({(2^2-\b^2)/(2*\b)*(\b*cos(x))^3},
             {(2^2-\b^2)/(2*\b)*(-2*(sin(x))^3)});}
            \temp 
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! ^^ I hadn't realized the \x.